# How to stop this webpage divs from resizing

Tags: html, css

When I click "Suggest Movie" and the page reloads, the title and logo of the page moves slightly, it goes into the right a little bit then comes back out, the site would be better without this little annoying thing because it will not look like it reloaded but unless the user has slow internet.

http://suggestmovie.net

I think that some css is loaded after wards which then makes the title bigger but I cannot find this css. I removed `.row` and `.container` to test it but it does not solve the problem.

Also for some reason this issue doesn't happen when I have the developer tools window up in chrome (F12)

Can anyone figure out which bit of css/reason is causing this resizing?

Comment: Ahh i see the Problem. The problem is, that the page is delivered to the browser right from the beginning. Then the browser displays what he has. After a short time the rest of the content arrives AND the scroll bar appears changing the width of the display what changes the content of you page. There lies the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack that MIGHT help would be to use the following CSS:

```
html {
       overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

that forces the scrollbar to be present at any times.